# Trying to send message to BUSMASTER from Python through Peak USB

Tags: python

This is the code---

```
from __future__ import print_function
import can

def send_one():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000,state = can.bus.BusState.PASSIVE
)

    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xc0ffee,
                      data=[0, 25, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1],
                      extended_id=True)
    try:
        bus.send(msg)
        print("Message sent on {}".format(bus.channel_info))
    except can.CanError:
        print("Message NOT sent")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_one()
```

and i am getting `OS` error and i tried to install `openslide` but that did not get imported. PLEASE help

Comment: Please include the entire error message. The formatting of your code is incomplete.

Comment: Error has been resolved, but the output cannot be seen in BUSMATER. Please let me know where the output should  be seen.Thank YOU

Comment: It might be worth it to write an answer for this question first, and then start a new one for the new problem.